# Irreducible polynomial over $GF(32)$

Tags: finite-fields, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

How to choose an irreducible polynomial of degree $2$ over $GF(2^5)$ assuming that $GF(2^5)$ has been constructed starting from $GF(2)$ with $x^5+x^2+1$ as irreducible polynomial?

Comment: Hint: $GF(2^5)$ intersects trivially with $GF(2^2)$, so the same polynomial that gives you $GF(2^2)$... (technically for this idea to work *intersects trivially* should be replaced with *is linearly disjoint*, but it comes to the same thing).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So, I can choose x^2+x+1 as irreducible polynomial over GF(2^5) ?

Comment: Correct. That polynomial remains irreducible over $GF(2^5)$ because it has no zeros there, and is of degree $\le3$.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!